# Accessing later index in array using enumerate(array) Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, enumerate

hey guys, how would you access an array from array[n] in an array of 100 floats in this for loop (i need the enumerate):

```
for index,value in enumerate(array):
    #do stuff with array[n]
    n=n+1
```

im trying to make it so that it operates in a smaller and smaller space each iteration..

thanks

Comment: This question is close to meaningless. What is `n`?  What does "access from array[n]" mean? What does "operate in a smaller and smaller space each iteration" mean? Give examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: srry, ok so if i have an array of 100 floats, I want the for loop's 1st iteration to access [1] through [100], 2nd: [2]-[100], 3rd: [3]-[100],...,99th: [99]-[100]. n is just some arbitrary number.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably clarify whether you mean a list, a [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array, an [array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), or something else...

That having been said, it sounds like you want to slice whatever your "array" is.   Perhaps something like this?:

```
data = range(10)
for i in range(len(data)):
    print data[i:]
```

Which would output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9]
[9]
```

Hope that helps a bit, anyway...

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = range(10)

for n, N in enumerate(lst):
    print lst[n:]
```